# React handleChange fuction store one input field as number - everything else as string in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

I fairly new to React and JS. I am building an account form as part of a larger form. Users can dynamically add as many "account inputs" as they need to populate. I can currently capture the state of these forms in an array. However all three properties are stored as type `string` - for `balance`, I need to store this as a number. I know I can use `parseFloat()` to make this happen. But I cant quite work it out?

How can I update my existing `handleInputChange` function to check if the `name` is `balance`, and if so... `parseFloat(value)`?

Everything else is working fine in this form, but my balance data is being stored as a string in my db.

Also open to advice if there is a better function to convert to a number

Code below:

```
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import AddCircleOutlineIcon from "@mui/icons-material/AddCircleOutline";
import RemoveCircleOutlineIcon from "@mui/icons-material/RemoveCircleOutline";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import { TextField, Typography } from "@mui/material";

function AccountsForm({ accountInputList, setAccountInputList }) {
  // handle input change
  const handleInputChange = (e, index) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const list = [...accountInputList];
    list[index][name] = value;
    setAccountInputList(list);
    console.log(accountInputList);
  };

  // handle click event of the Remove button
  const handleRemoveClick = (index) => {
    const list = [...accountInputList];
    list.splice(index, 1);
    setAccountInputList(list);
  };

  // handle click event of the Add button
  const handleAddClick = () => {
    setAccountInputList([
      ...accountInputList,
      { balance: "", name: "", type: "" },
    ]);
  };

  return (
    <Box marginTop={1}>
      <Typography id="modal-modal-enddate" sx={{ mt: 2, mb: 1 }}>
        Add Account
      </Typography>
      {accountInputList.map((x, i) => {
        return (
          <Box key={i} marginTop={1}>
            <TextField
              sx={{ width: "12ch" }}
              name="balance"
              label="Balance"
              value={x.balance}
              onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, i)}
            />
            <TextField
              sx={{ width: "12ch" }}
              name="name"
              label="Name"
              value={x.name}
              onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, i)}
            />
            <TextField
              sx={{ width: "12ch" }}
              name="type"
              label="Description"
              value={x.type}
              onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, i)}
            />
            {accountInputList.length !== 1 && (
              <IconButton onClick={() => handleRemoveClick(i)}>
                <RemoveCircleOutlineIcon />
              </IconButton>
            )}
            {accountInputList.length - 1 === i && (
              <IconButton onClick={handleAddClick}>
                <AddCircleOutlineIcon />
              </IconButton>
            )}
          </Box>
        );
      })}
    </Box>
  );
}

export default AccountsForm;
```

Inside `handleInputChange` ive tried a variety of if statements and switch statements, but nothing seems to work. I need my form state stored as an array of accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the input's name:

```js
list[index][name] = name === 'balance' ? +value : value;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the speedy response. its so obvious its painful! Derp. This seems to only allow full numbers (no decimals.) Any suggestions for this?

Comment: @JoshBGosh You could add `type="number"` to the `TextField` for the balance.

Comment: Thank you for your help, both good options.